# DELETE With group by

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Table with the following

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Poll](
    [PollID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LoginID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [FacilityID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PolledAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
```

I have to empty this table out nightly...but leave the maximum row based on the `PolledAt` field groupped by the `LoginID` field.  Meaning a user (LoginID) has multiple rows, by the end of the night that user should only have one row after the delete.  That row should be the `MAX(PolledAt)` value.

I can get the records I dont want to delete with this:

```
SELECT
    LoginID,
    MAX(PolledAt) AS MaxPolledAt
FROM
    Poll
GROUP BY
    LoginID
```

But then I dont know how to form my delete because I am not displaying the primary key which is the pollid.  I need to take the result of the above select and delete everything except what that select returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and the [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function to figure out what rows need to be deleted.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/465c9/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Poll](
    [PollID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LoginID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [FacilityID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PolledAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
);


insert into Poll values(1, 1, getdate());
insert into Poll values(1, 1, getdate()+1);
insert into Poll values(1, 1, getdate()+2);
insert into Poll values(1, 1, getdate()+3);
insert into Poll values(2, 2, getdate()+4);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with C as
(
  select row_number() over(partition by LoginID order by PolledAt desc) as rn
  from Poll
)
delete from C
where rn > 1;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/465c9/1/0)**:

**Query 2**:

```
select *
from Poll;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/465c9/1/1)**:

```
| POLLID | LOGINID | FACILITYID |                        POLLEDAT |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|      4 |       1 |          1 | February, 08 2013 21:48:34+0000 |
|      5 |       2 |          2 | February, 09 2013 21:48:34+0000 |
```